# How to draw a dashed Polyline with Arrow at endpoint in Google Maps v3 api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I would like to draw a dashed Polyline with an arrow at the end.  The problem is that it seems the strokeOpacity is meant to go on the array of icons, but it needs to be 0 for a dashed line, while it needs to be positive to draw an arrow.  Is there a way around this?

Here is an example that illustrates the quandary: https://jsfiddle.net/hrabinowitz/1ckk2c2L/18/

And the crucial code is the javascript:

```
// This example converts a polyline to a dashed line, by
// setting the opacity of the polyline to 0, and drawing an opaque symbol
// at a regular interval on the polyline.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: {lat: 20.291, lng: 153.027},
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });

  // Define a symbol using SVG path notation, with an opacity of 1.
  var lineSymbol = {
    path: 'M 0,-1 0,1',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    scale: 4
  };

  var arrowSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
    strokeColor: 'red'
  }

  // Create the polyline.  If strokeOpacity is 0, the dashedLine shows.  
  // If strokeOpacity is 1, the arrow shows. 
  // How to show both? 
  var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [{lat: 22.291, lng: 153.027}, {lat: 18.291, lng: 153.027}],
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    icons: [{
      icon: lineSymbol,
      offset: '0',
      repeat: '20px',
      strokeOpacity: 1
    },
    {
      icon: arrowSymbol,
      offset: '100%',
      strokeOpacity: 1,
      strokeColor: 'black'
    }
    ],
    map: map
  });
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the opacity on the arrow symbol:

```
  icon: {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
    offset: '100%',
    fillColor: "black",
    fillOpacity: 1,
    strokeOpacity: 1,
  }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/sb03cfqp/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: {
      lat: 20.291,
      lng: 153.027
    },
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });

  var lineSymbol = {
    path: 'M 0,-1 0,1',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    scale: 4
  };

  var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [{
      lat: 22.291,
      lng: 153.027
    }, {
      lat: 18.291,
      lng: 153.027
    }],
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    icons: [{
      icon: lineSymbol,
      offset: '0',
      repeat: '20px'
    }, {
      icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
        offset: '100%',
        fillColor: "black",
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeOpacity: 1,
      }
    }],
    map: map
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk">
</script>
```